# How to find L value of a coil?

Tags: inductance, coil

[image: My Circuit]

[image: This is the coil I want to find L for]

I am a newbie at electronics and was hoping I could find some help. I have a coil with a removable iron core, photo for which is given above. I tried to find L1 or the inductance of the coil. I was using the circuit shown in the diagram and a cheap multimeter. I tried applying AC and DC voltage to it. I was wanting to find the voltage drop in R1 so I can use it to find XL or the Inductive reactance, which I would use to find L1. But I am not getting any voltage drop in the resistor across points AB (my multimeter might not be good enough to measure a really . Both in AC and DC. Is it because the coil I am using will have such a high L value that all the voltage is dropping across the coil? Is there anyway of doing this without an oscilloscope, function generator and such tools?

Comment: I think you are making a measurement error. The inductance will be about 1 henry and 1 henry at 50 Hz is about 314 ohms. Try again and confirm there is no wire broken by measuring the coil's dc resistance.

Comment: Assuming the inductance is that high, it would only be 0.3V drop.. and the DC resistance of the coil is going to cause significant error!

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply Andy. The coil might be broken. I don't get any resistance value for the coil when I check it with the my mutlimeter.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I checked the voltages by passing an AC current. Voltage AD was 10.3 and voltage CD is 10.1V . Are these the values I can expect?Can I assume that the voltage drop across AB is 0.2 V (in my mind I cant simply subtract the input voltage and the voltage across the inducting coil because they will not be in phase)? Also can I assume the Voltage reading across CD 10.1 is the actual voltage drop across the coil?

Comment: "I don't get any resistance value for the coil when I check it with the my multimeter" If you measure infinite DC resistance with a multimeter then the coil is broken. You should ALWAYS be able to measure the DC resistance and it must be much lower than 1 M ohm. BTW, also check that your meter is OK (short the pins, it must read around 0 ohms).

Comment: If there's no voltage being dropped across R1, that's because there's no current  through it, and if there's no current through it that'll be because there's no connection back to the source through the solenoid, which means that the solenoid's winding is open.  To find out for sure, measure the current.  If it's zero, then that's the proof that there's an open somewhere.

Comment: Blowing up the image shows that there's wire enamel visible on the far terminal, so there may be a faulty solder joint there. Touch it up and check the resistance again and you might be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Kunal first says "voltage AD was 10.3" then "voltage CD is 10.1V" which clearly means 0.2v must be across R1. Perhaps it was just a poor connection. If 0.2v is across 10k R1, then the current through the series circuit must be I=E/R, I=0.2v/10k, I=20µV, or 0.02mV, or 0.00002v. This is going to be challenging for most meters to measure accurately. Can you raise the supply voltage?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to determine an inductance is by using an RLC measuring bridge. Since this isn't a very cheap solution, most of the time the step response of an RL circuit is used in combination with an oscilloscope.

For more details have a look a this site:

[How to Measure Inductance?](http://daycounter.com/Articles/How-To-Measure-Inductance.phtml)